# z-value of a projected 3d point

Tags: graphics, matrix, 3d, projection, frustum

After a 3d point has been transformed by a perspective projection matrix, what do the Z coordinate stand for? Distance from the 'eye'? Distance from the near clip plane? None of this?

**Edit**

I've set up a matrix using the glFustrum definition found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.opengl/doc/openglrf/glFrustum.htm).

Then, I transform a 3D point with that matrix.

I'm left with a 3D point where X and Y are the coordinates of the point on the near frustum face, and Z, supposedly a depth information that I have a hard time exploiting.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you are doing? Usually the projection matrix will be 4x3, i.e. the resulting vector will not contain a z coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformed z (that you use as denominator for dividing x and y) is the distance from the eye in the perpendicular direction to the projection plane, scaled so that the projection plane is at distance 1.

Comment: Actually, I'm dividing x, y and z by w. Isn't what's called "perspective division"? My brain hurts!

Comment: OpenGL approach uses "clipping coordinates" that I never found useful (clipping is better done in object space) and that's why i'm used to w=z. However even including that step still the w coordinate is the normalized distance from the projection plane and shouldn't change z except for pure scaling. In other words to get from eye coordinates to clip coordinates you only change x and y to "straighten" the side planes of the camera transforming a truncated pyramid in a cube.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while for me, but if you have the X and Y coordinates on the frustrum, does not the Z control the layer order?